# How would I create a websocket server using an external REST api?

Tags: node.js, rest, websocket

There's an external REST api that I'd like to use, but they don't offer a websocket api so I was thinking of making one myself using their REST api.

What I was thinking of doing is creating a websocket server, then making a GET request to the REST api every minute or so within that server, and then send the response to my frontend using websockets.

Is there any reason this wouldn't work, or is there a better way of accomplishing this?